# There exists both implicit conversions from 'float' and 'float' and from 'float' to 'float'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, unity-game-engine

In probably the best error message I've gotten in awhile, I'm curious as to what went wrong.

The original code

```
float currElbowAngle = LeftArm ? Elbow.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y 
                               : 360f - Elbow.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y
```

I'm using Unity3d and C#; LeftArm is a `bool` type and according to [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3-y.html) `Elbow.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y` returns a `float` value.

This code gives me the error :

> There exists both implicit conversions from 'float' and 'float' and
>   from 'float' to 'float'

This fixes it:

```
float currElbowAngle = LeftArm ? (float) Elbow.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y 
                               : 360f - Elbow.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y
```

So my question is this: What was that error trying to communicate and what actually went wrong?

**Update 1:** Elbow is a `GameObject` and this error is in Visual Studio

Comment: that this should be error of unity3d framework i guess so

Comment: Did they create their own type called `float`?

Comment: Is Elbow really a `GameObject` or `Component`? I just tried `bool b = true; float currElbowAngle = b ?transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y : 360f - transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y;` and it worked.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Seems like MonoDevelop and Visual Studio behave different. My test was in MonoDevelop. But anyway a pretty strange behaviour. Maybe one of the C# gurus can explain :)

Comment: I wonder if the compiler's parsing logic might be using two different kinds of "float" internally.  I don't know what C#'s exact rules for floating-point are, but it might possibly use the name `float` to refer both to things that could only be 32-bit floats and to things that be could use longer types if convenient.  For example, if all variables are of type `float`, a system using 8087-style math could evaluate `f=x+y+z` most quickly as `f=(float)((FpuDouble)x+(FpuDouble)y+(FpuDouble)z)`) [`FpuDouble` referring to the 80-bit 8087 internal float type not available to .net user code].

Comment: I think what the error is trying to communicate is that it's got expressions of two different types on either side of the `:` in the conditional operator, and implicit conversions are available in both directions - so it's unable to pick a single "best" type and decide which conversion to make. By adding your explicit conversion, it's now seeing types on both sides with the same type, so it can compile. But it does seem you're working in an environment with two types called `float`. Fun.

Comment: Any idea how I could see more information on each of those "float" types?

Comment: Oh man, I'm jealous. The most interesting I've ever seen has been grammatical errors...

Comment: @supercat My guess is it is having trouble with the true branch being an lvalue, and the false branch being an rvalue. Both being float should be sufficient, but I'm guessing the symantic analyzer is seeing a difference and doesn't like it.

Comment: What is the data type of `Elbow.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y`?

Comment: @doug65536: I don't think lvalue vs rvalue would be a problem, since that situation occurs all the time.  On the other hand, the distinction between "known 32-bit float" and "temporary float" may be more obscure.

Comment: Actually, it kind of looks like it's complaining about three floats, from the text of the error: "float **and** float **and** float **to** float" - could just be a messy error message though

Comment: @supercat I don't think it should be a problem either. But by the looks of the (working) workaround, it's the most logical explanation I could think of.

Comment: @supercat "known temporary float" is an rvalue. "named memory location" is an lvalue.

Comment: @doug65536: I think I've got it: a value of type `float` may be most expediently copied from one variable to another by loading it into an integer register and storing it, but one can only perform math on such values if they're loaded into floating-point registers.  The compiler uses two different types internally for "float stored in fp register" versus "float stored in int register", and the conditional operator is ending up with one of each.  The proper course of action would either be to have the "straight copy" branch use a floating-point load, but the compiler can't figure that out.

Comment: @supercat The C# compiler generates IL, a stack based virtual machine language where operands are pushed onto a stack and reduction operations reduce it and optionally push a result. The compiler knows nothing of registers when compiling C# to IL. That is done much later at run time by the just-in-time compiler or by ngen. At this level, type conversions are as close as it should have to get to code level.

Comment: @doug65536: Perhaps, but I'm curious if perhaps the C# compiler does something "creative" with assignments from one `float` variable to another.  I know that the CLR is fiercely protective when it comes to ensuring that only reference types can be written to reference-type storage locations, since allowing even one reference-type storage location to be overwritten with a value type could (and likely would) cause the whole world to come crashing down, but integer operations for a simple FP assignment might still be a useful optimization--one that might perhaps be left to the JIT, but...

Comment: ...one the compiler might want to worry about in any event.  My intuition would suggest that there's something "special" about `float`, though I don't know what (perhaps promotion rules, though C# doesn't have any really nice ones; if I were designing a language, I'd include a `double` and a `fuzzyDouble` type, with the rules `float` could be convertible to and from `fuzzydouble`, and that operations involving `double` and `fuzzyDouble` would yield `fuzzyDouble`.  Saying `float1 = float2+double;` isn't apt to lose any real precision in the assignment, and shouldn't require a cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary (e?a:b) operator is slightly trickier for the type system, because both sides need to give the same return type. I wouldn't be surprised if there were a subtle bug there. It's good that compliers make us laugh once in a while.

This probably fixes it too:

```
float currElbowAngle = LeftArm ? 0.0f + Elbow.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y 
                               : 360f - Elbow.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.y
```

I'm speculating that the trouble is that your true branch is an lvalue and the false branch is an rvalue. My workaround makes both branches an rvalue.